# ubuntu 16.04 unable to read htc device

Tags: 16.04, phone

I am trying to connect my HTC desire 820 to my laptop with a usb cable, to copy some files from phone to laptop. Ubuntu doen't show any error messages but also doesn't  read the htc device.

What should I do to fix it?
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I didn't have this kind of issue in 14.04

Comment: Are you sure that the phone is unlocked and that the memory has no lock on it?

Comment: i installed an application from storemagazin and now it`s seeing the device but it can`t open the micro SD folders and it show this message: "unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again. unhandled error message. Couldn`t find matching undev device"....

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the phone is using the wrong type of USB connection by default. Try dragging the notification bar down and then clicking on the USB settings to see what the options are. Usually, changing the connection type should be enough to allow your computer to see it.

Edit: I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm editing this...

Have you tried looking at the USB settings as mentioned above? Do you see options like "connect via MTP" or "connect via PTP"?

To transfer files, you need to use MTP. I'm guessing your phone is trying to use PTP by default.

Answer (score 0):

it`s show nothing when i plug the htc phone. i tried to change the  htc with a samsung s6 and it`s show the message "unable to mount device" so it seems that the usb cable is ok  and the problem is at phone?